# vxprint equivalent in Solaris volume manager

Tags: solaris, veritas

vxprint -m -g  command in vxvm give lot of inofrmation about the volume like rid , pub offsets etc. Is there a command in solaris volume manager to get the such information?

and  vxprint -F %len -g  -v   gives volume length in blocks. Is there any command in solaris volume manager to get length information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `metastat` command it provides some of the information you appear to be looking for e.g. (from man metastat)

```
# metastat
 d2: Concat/Stripe
     Size: 204800 blocks
     Stripe 0:
         Device              Start Block  Dbase State        Hot Spare
         d0                         0     No    Okay

 d0: Soft Partition
     Component: c0t3d0s0
     Status: Okay
     Size: 204800 blocks
         Extent              Start Block  Block count
              0                      129       204800

 d3: Soft Partition
     Component: d2
     Status: Okay
     Size: 202752 blocks
          Extent              Start Block  Block count
               0                      129       202752
```